# VBA learner - function call on left-hand

Tags: excel, vba

just started learning VBA and in one of my lesson I get to work with dates. I wrote the following code:

```
Sub Aula11 () 

Dim data1 as date

Dim data2 as date

Dim diferençadatas as long

Data1 = Date 

Data2 = #2/8/2018#

diferençadatas = data1 – data2 

MsgBox = “Passaram” & diferençadatas & “dias desde o dia 8 de Fevereiro de 2018”

End Sub
```

When I hit run, I get the following message: "Compile error: Function call on left-hand side of assignement must return Variant or Object" on subroutine line (line 1).

I don't understand what's wrong, I used date functions before and the first line was the same. Sorry about my dumb question, just trying to learn something so differently from what I'm used to :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are a learner, consider not using variable names with letters deviating from the 26 standard letters of the English alphabet. Thus, `diferencadatas` could become easily `diferençadatas`.

As a second best practice - please name the variables in English. Thus a colleague who does not speak Portuguese can also take over your code easily.

This works quite ok:

```
Sub Aula11()

    Dim data1 As Date
    Dim data2 As Date
    Dim diferencadatas As Long

    data1 = Date
    data2 = #2/8/2018#
    diferencadatas = data1 - data2
    MsgBox ("Passaram" & diferencadatas & "dias desde o dia 8 Fevereiro de 2018")

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Took me a long time to notice the problem was the equal sign. Will do the good practices u refered moving forward.

Comment: @Hugo - you are welcome :). Feel free to mark the answer as accepted - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers